# error moving from jquery 1.8.1 to jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, render

i need to use the bootstrap js file but my jquery plugin was 1.8.1. so i updated my jquery to 1.9.1. how ever when i try to render a template now with the new version it throws the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Error: view.hlp(...) is not a function.
    at Function.st.error (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at ft (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at wt (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.st [as find] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at init.find (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4)
    at e.fn.init.init (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at new e.fn.init (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2)
    at b (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.renderMarket (List.js:174)
    at Object.<anonymous> (List.js:502)
```

this is my renderMarket call

```
renderMarket: function (market, $contentholder) {
            var $market = $('.List div.marketcontainer[dataID=' + market.MarketID + ']');
            if ($market.length < 1) {

                $market = $($('#markettmpl').render(market)).appendTo($contentholder.children(".marketlist")); //throws an error here
            } else {
                var $newMarket = $($('#markettmpl').render(market));
                $market.replaceWith($newMarket);
                $market = $newMarket;
            }

            if (market.MarketOptions.length > 0) {
                    var dropper = $('<div class="Clicker"></div>');
                    dropper.append(exotics);
                    $market.find('.loader').before(dropper);
                }
                var $marketTemplate = $('#' + market.Sport + 'tmpl').length > 0 ? $('#' + market.Sport + 'tmpl') : $('#DEFAULTtmpl');
                var $marketoptions = $($marketTemplate.render(market)).appendTo($market.find(".marketoptionslist"));
                var $optionsTemplate = $('#' + market + 'optiontmpl').length > 0 ? $('#' + market + 'optiontmpl') : $('#DEFAULToptiontmpl');
                $marketoptions.children("tbody").append($optionsTemplate.render(market.MarketOptions));
            }
            else {
                //$market.append($('#NoMarketOptions').render({}));
                $market.children('h3 + div').hide();
                $market.addClass('closed');
            }
            return $market;
        },
```

it works fine with jquery 1.8.1 but now with 1.9.1 its not rendering. what am i doing wrong?

these are the scripts i added

```
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../../../Scripts/jsRender.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you also need to upgrade the version of jsRender. Can you tell which version you're using?

Comment: @kakamg0 i am using v1.0.0-beta